# How can i make sure my backend styling doesn't interfere with frontend styling (admin/frontend)

Tags: vue.js, sass, single-page-application, vue-router

So i created my first SPA vue app and styled my frontend. then i went ahead and started working on my admin backend, and im stuck with the styling i am trying to integrate a third party template just for the backend but it interferes with the frontend styling.

i tried using scoped for the backend styling, the issue is that first of all the frontend styling still exists and interferes, secondly it feels wrong having to bring in a full bootstrap in a scoped style tag and not have it loaded before.

i also tried using deep but that increases the load time as well.

how can i dynamically add a admin stylesheet just for the backend truth is the question is on the frontend how can i keep it to the frontend

```
<style lang="scss" scoped>
    @import "../sass/admin/admin.scss";
</style>
<template>
  <div id="admin-wrapper">
      <router-view></router-view>
  </div>
</template>
```

what i am trying to achieve is to have totally separate stylesheets load on the two parts of the application

Comment: What do you mean by "backend" and "frontend"?

Comment: @miir admin vs user

Comment: For calibrating terminology, backend refers server-side logic and systems, things the user's device/browser is interacting with through the frontend. 
Frontend means what we load into the user's device/browser for the user to interact with. So in this case, both admin and user are frontend users, but using two different interfaces.

Comment: can you share what the user's template looks like? And where you are setting the stylesheets for the user?